# use Lodash to sort array of object by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I am trying to sort an array by 'name' value (using Lodash). I used the Lodash docs to create the solution below however .orderBy doesn't seem to be having any affect at all. Can anyone shed some light on the correct way to sort array?

**Chars Array**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":25,
      "name":"Anakin Skywalker",
      "createdAt":"2017-04-12T12:48:55.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-04-12T12:48:55.000Z"
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Luke Skywalker",
      "createdAt":"2017-04-12T11:25:03.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-04-12T11:25:03.000Z"
   }
]
```

**Function Code**

```
 var chars = this.state.characters;

 _.orderBy(chars, 'name', 'asc'); // Use Lodash to sort array by 'name'

 this.setState({characters: chars})
```

Answer (score 289, accepted):

This method `orderBy` does not change the input array,
you have to assign the result to your array :

```
var chars = this.state.characters;

chars = _.orderBy(chars, ['name'],['asc']); // Use Lodash to sort array by 'name'

 this.setState({characters: chars})
```

Comment: That second parameter `['asc']` doesn't order ascending, to achieve that the way would be to add a `reverse()` after the `orderBy` (at least in version 4.17.15)

Comment: The documentation for 4.17.15 still says that the last parameter can be used to set the order : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy

Answer (score 82):

You can use lodash sortBy (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy).

Your code could be like:

```
const myArray = [  
   {  
      "id":25,
      "name":"Anakin Skywalker",
      "createdAt":"2017-04-12T12:48:55.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-04-12T12:48:55.000Z"
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Luke Skywalker",
      "createdAt":"2017-04-12T11:25:03.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-04-12T11:25:03.000Z"
   }
]

const myOrderedArray = _.sortBy(myArray, o => o.name)
```

Comment: You can also use the shorthand: `_.sortBy(myArray, 'name')`

Comment: Compared to `orderBy`, you can not pass sort type in `sortBy`, it always sorts by ascending order.

Answer (score 13):

If you need to sort by date, you could use this solution:

```
orderBy(items, (a) => new Date(a.createdAt), ['asc']) // or 'desc'
```

If you are using `moment` library, then:

```
orderBy(items, (a) => moment(a.createdAt), 'asc')
```

P.s. Note that the `lodash` doesn't sort dates in string format, so you must convert it to Date object.