# Need to sort the vuex Data i need to change computed property in a component result

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I need to sort the array which I am receiving after Axios and I need to sort value in ascending and descending also by the date. I don't really know how Vuex works and I need to create the sort function really fast. Can you guys please help me out?

```
methods: {
  sort() {
    return this.results = this.$store.getters.getResults.slice().reverse();
  },
}
const actions = {
  sort({commit}, payLoad){
    commit('setResults', )
 },
const mutations = {
  setResults (state, results) {
    state.results = results
  },
}
```

Can you tell me if I am doing correctly? I need to sort the array by its title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex Actions are powerful tools for executing asynchronous operations so if there's no reason to keep it in your component then I would dispatch the action to trigger your axios request in your Vuex actions. On the return result in your `then` function of your axios promise you can then sort your data and finally `commit` this sorted data to your Vuex store using the `setResults` mutation.

After this, any computed method in your components or template referencing the `$store.state.results` variable should update.

Comment: I tried to do it but I couldn't possibly do it can you help me on some other platform where you can see the whole code I would be very glad

Comment: Glad it worked - if it's solved your issue you can mark the answer as correct ;)

Comment: already did can you tell me one more thing is ti okay to use lodash for sorting or create my own method

Comment: Absolutely fine using lodash if you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371092/use-lodash-to-sort-array-of-object-by-value