# Handle Array of Object manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Below I have an array of objects

```
var data = [{
  "time": "1572024707.4763825",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "77777"
}, {
  "time": "1572024709.0991757",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "77777"
}, {
  "time": "1572024704.4570136",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "555555"
}, {
  "time": "1572024708.3903246",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "77777"
}, {
  "time": "1572024699.7132683",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "66666"
}]
```

How can I restructure it to remove the repeating id's with the oldest time

I tried to pull all the unique IDs from the array so I can loop through the data array but then the code started to get too long.

```
  data.forEach(item => {

    IDs.push(item.id);
  });

  var unqIDs = [...new Set(IDs)];
  console.log(unqIDs);
```

## the output should look like this

```
outPutShouldBe = [{
  "time": "1572024699.7132683",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "66666"
},{
  "time": "1572024709.0991757",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "77777"
},  {"time": "1572024704.4570136",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "555555"
}
]
```

Comment: What does "the code started to get too long" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object mapping ids to the item w/ the earliest time of those with that id:

```
var keydata = {};
data.forEach(item=>{ 
    var p = keydata[item.id]; 
    if ( !p || p.time>item.time ) { 
        keydata[item.id] = item; 
    }});
```

Now gather up the values in that object:

```
var newdata = [];
for ( var k in keydata ) { 
    newdata.push(keydata[k]);
}
```

or the more elegant (thanks, @TulioF.):

```
var newdata = Object.values(keydata)
```

Comment: For your second step, you could do `Object.values(keydata)` to get the dictionary values.

Answer (score 4):

Using forEach() find() filter() and filter() to decide which element to return

```js
var data = [{"time": "1572024707.4763825","rssi": "32","id": "77777"},{"time": "1572024709.0991757","rssi": "32","id": "77777"}, {"time": "1572024704.4570136","rssi": "32","id": "555555"}, {"time": "1572024708.3903246","rssi": "32","id": "77777"}, {"time": "1572024699.7132683","rssi": "32","id": "66666"}]

let resultsArray = []

data.forEach(obj=>{
  const foundObj = resultsArray.find(data => data.id === obj.id)

  if(foundObj && new Date(foundObj.time) > new Date(obj.time)){
     const filteredArray = resultsArray.filter(data => data.id === obj.id)
     resultsArray = [...filteredArray , foundObj]
  } else if (!foundObj){
     resultsArray.push(obj)
  }
})

console.log(resultsArray)
```

Comment: I'll study this one in more detail later, but it did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

You coud take an object as hash table and get the values directly.

```js
var data = [{ time: "1572024707.4763825", rssi: "32", id: "77777" }, { time: "1572024709.0991757", rssi: "32", id: "77777" }, { time: "1572024704.4570136", rssi: "32", id: "555555" }, { time: "1572024708.3903246", rssi: "32", id: "77777" }, { time: "1572024699.7132683", rssi: "32", id: "66666" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.id] || +r[o.id].time > +o.time) r[o.id] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do something like this :

```
let existMap = {};
data.filter(val => {
  if((val.id in existMap) && (val.time>existMap[val.id])) return;
  else{
    existMap[val.id] = val.time;
    return true;
  }
})
console.log(result)
```

The condition can be changed based on requirement. just want to reference for your problem.

Comment: How does this "remove the repeating id's with the oldest time"?

Comment: Updated my code. The condition can change based on the requirement

Answer (score 0):

use `lodash` to sort the array in descending order or ascending order as per your need (`desc`, `asc`) and get the zeroth object. try something like this. [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) and [orderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43371146/5124488)

```
var data = [{
  "time": "1572024707.4763825",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "77777"
}, ....];

let idsSet = new Set();

data.map(item=> idsSet.add(item.id));

let idsArr = Array.from(idsSet);

let newArr = [];
idsArr.map(id=>{
let tempArray = data.filter(item => item.id === id);
return newArr.push((_.orderBy(tempArray, ['time'],['desc']))[0]);
} )

console.log(newArr);
```

**console output**

```
[ {
  "time": "1572024709.0991757",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "77777"
}, {
  "time": "1572024704.4570136",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "555555"
},  {
  "time": "1572024699.7132683",
  "rssi": "32",
  "id": "66666"
}];
```