# How to load contacts alphabetically in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-contacts

I am creating a react native app to load phone book contacts to my app [using this library.](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select) I loaded contact correctly in my app. But contacts not in alphabetically order. Now I wanted to load contacts alphabetically order. How can I do that?

[This is the error after adding sorting part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeBrq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Const tmpArray = _.sortBy(arrFinal, 'fullname')`than`this.setState({ contactList: tmpArray, isLoading: false })`

Answer (score 0):

You can modified [library code](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select). In Contacts.js file at line no 77, you will find `getListOfContacts = () => {`. Once you are done with change and you fill this feature should be in this library, Please raise PR for the same.

Comment: What  should  I add as additional code? How to sort contacts?

Comment: You can use lodash for sorting based on name.

Comment: URL for lodash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371092/use-lodash-to-sort-array-of-object-by-value

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this.

Comment: If my answer correct. you please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I tried it. but nothing will happen. in my tab2.js i added  `this.arrayholder = _.sortBy(arrFinal, 'fullname')`. but it not change anything else.

Comment: @Sidath, you need to write it. In contact.Js file not in tab2.js.

Comment: yeah, I right it in contact,js file. I copied that code into my tab2.js file. and after I added the above code. But nothing changed.

Comment: You can check it here: (https://github.com/SidathDananjaya/Event-App/blob/master/Event-App/src/HomeTabs/tab2.js)

Comment: I added ` _.sortBy(arrFinal, 'fullname')` before  `this.setState({ contactList: arrFinal, isLoading: false }) `. But nothing changed. I messed up with this code.

Comment: I added your code also. `arrFinal = _.sortBy(arrFinal, 'fullname')
      this.setState({ contactList: arrFinal, isLoading: false })
      this.arrayholder = arrFinal` . But it show  "arrFinal" is read-only.

Comment: Here you can see the error. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeBrq.png)