# sort whole object with specific (key->value) in JavaScript alphabetically?

Tags: javascript

I have an array in JavaScript that looks like

```
[
   {
      "name":"a",
      "phoneNo":"1"
   },
   {
      "name":"X",
      "phoneNo":"3"
   },
   {
      "name":"A",
      "phoneNo":"2"
   },
   {
      "name":"b",
      "phoneNo":"4"
   },
   {
      "name":"c",
      "phoneNo":"5"
   },
   {
      "name":"D",
      "phoneNo":"6"
   }
]
```

and I want to sort it by the name value in each array, alphabetically. NOTE: all name will be converted to lowercase first.
I am stuck with this problem and I tried alot to solve it myself and also tried some research but I did'nt found something. **Help!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using JS

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript)

```js
const arr = [
   {
      "name":"a",
      "phoneNo":"1"
   },
   {
      "name":"X",
      "phoneNo":"3"
   },
   {
      "name":"A",
      "phoneNo":"2"
   },
   {
      "name":"b",
      "phoneNo":"4"
   },
   {
      "name":"c",
      "phoneNo":"5"
   },
   {
      "name":"D",
      "phoneNo":"6"
   }
]

console.log(arr.sort(function(a, b){
 var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase();
 if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
  return -1;
 if (nameA > nameB)
  return 1;
 return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
}));
```

Comment: @RehanShah You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash, you can easily solve the problem: [use Lodash to sort array of object by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371092/use-lodash-to-sort-array-of-object-by-value)

```
_.sortBy(myArray, o => o.name.toLowerCase())
```