# How to add sorting ability to data list?

Tags: javascript, html, dataframe, sorting, html-lists

Here I have list containing data about countries (name, area etc.) grouped by subregions. How do I add sorting option, such that after clicking on, for example, name on the very top countries would be sorted by names ascending or descending and after clicking once again countries would sort inversely to previous state. Multiple sorts could be handled at the same time, so there would be option to sort, for example, by area and capitals. I would be very grateful for your help, here is the code snippet:

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
let ul = document.createElement('ul');

div.appendChild(ul);
async function f() {
    //fetching and sorting data by regions and subregions
    const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
    const data = await res.json();
    data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.region > b.region) return 1;
        else if (a.region < b.region) return -1
        else {
            if (a.subregion > b.subregion) return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
    });
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const accordion = document.createElement('div');
    const olWrapper = document.getElementById('listWrapper');   
    const subRegionWrapper = document.getElementById('subRegionWrapper');

    const subRegions = data.reduce((r, a) => {
        r[a.subregion] = r[a.subregion] || [];
        r[a.subregion].push(a);
        return r;
    }, {});

   const dropdownValues = Object.entries(subRegions);
    dropdownValues.forEach(subRegion => {
      const accordionWrapper = document.createElement('div');
      const panel = document.createElement('div');
      panel.classList.add('panel');
      accordionWrapper.classList.add('accordion');

      const totalArea = subRegion[1].reduce((acc, curr) => acc+curr.area,0);
      const totalPopulation = subRegion[1].reduce((acc, curr) => acc+curr.population,0);
      const li = createSubregion(subRegion[0], totalPopulation, totalArea);

      accordionWrapper.appendChild(li);
      accordion.appendChild(accordionWrapper);

      subRegion[1].forEach(item => {
          const subLi = createCountry(item.name.common, item.capital, item.area, item.population);
          const subOl = document.createElement('ol');
          subOl.appendChild(subLi);
          panel.appendChild(subOl);
          accordion.appendChild(panel);
      });

     accordionWrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        const panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
          panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          panel.style.display = "block";
        }
     });
    });
  
  container.appendChild(accordion);
}

function createSubregion(name, population, area) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("class", "subregion");

    var header = document.createElement("div");
    header.setAttribute("class", "subregion-header disp-flex");

    var nameDiv = document.createElement("div");

    var nameh2 = document.createElement("h2");
    nameh2.innerText = name;

    nameDiv.appendChild(nameh2);
    header.append(nameDiv);

    var emptyDiv = document.createElement("div");
    header.appendChild(emptyDiv);

    var populationDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var populationh2 = document.createElement("h3");
    populationh2.innerText = population;

    populationDiv.appendChild(populationh2);
    header.append(populationDiv);

    var areaDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var areah2 = document.createElement("h3");
    areah2.innerText = area;

    areaDiv.appendChild(areah2);
    header.append(areaDiv);

    li.appendChild(header);
    return li;
}

function createCountry(name, capital, area, population) {
    var country = document.createElement("li");
    country.setAttribute("class", "country disp-flex")

    var namediv = document.createElement("div");
    var nameh4 = document.createElement("h4");
    nameh4.innerText = name;
    namediv.appendChild(nameh4);
    country.appendChild(namediv);

    var capitaldiv = document.createElement("div");
    var capitalh4 = document.createElement("h4");
    capitalh4.innerText = capital;
    capitaldiv.appendChild(capitalh4);
    country.appendChild(capitaldiv);

    var popdiv = document.createElement("div");
    var poph4 = document.createElement("h4");
    poph4.innerText = population;
    popdiv.appendChild(poph4);
    country.appendChild(popdiv);

    var areadiv = document.createElement("div");
    var areah4 = document.createElement("h4");
    areah4.innerText = area;
    areadiv.appendChild(areah4);
    country.appendChild(areadiv);


    return country;
}

f();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 15%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
}
header{
  margin: 0 10%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 22px 0;
    color:rgb(5, 5, 5);
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    outline: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    list-style-position: inside;
    color: blue;
}

ul ol { 
    color: rgb(197, 105, 18);
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: 0.4rem 0;
}
.country{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.disp-flex{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.disp-flex > div{
    width:23%;
    padding:15px 0px;
}


.subregion-header>div:nth-child(1){
    position: relative;
    left:30px;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 15px 2px;
}

.accordion li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main class="container">
        <header>
            <div id="name">
                <h1>Name</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="capital">
                <h1>Capital</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="population">
                <h1>Population</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="area">
                <h1>Area</h1>
            </div>

        </header>

      
      <div id="container"></div>
      <div id="subRegionWrapper"> </div>
      <div id="listWrapper"></div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371092/use-lodash-to-sort-array-of-object-by-value

Make sure you search SO before you ask a question :)

Comment: Ok it seems to solve the problem, but I would like not to use libraries.